# How to parse individual data fields from a string pulled from a .txt file in c#

Tags: c#, parsing

I am currently working on a project to parse production reports. The production reports get uploaded to our site and then a request is put in to parse them. The files are placed in a SqlServer database that we can reference to pull the file into the code. The problem I'm facing is that after accessing the .txt file in my code, I am unaware how to parse the individual fields of data from each line as the program reads through the file. I am attempting to store values from each line into a prepared variable table, parse the data from the line back into a SqlServer database, then move onto the next line and repeat. This  is the block of code I currently have. The if statement skips the lines of the file that are unimportant, the else statement is where I would like to parse the data from each line.

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileLocation);
string strAllFile = reader.ReadToEnd().Replace("\r\n\n", "\n").Replace("\r\n", "\n").Replace("\n\r", "\n");
string[] arrLines = strAllFile.Split(new char[] { '\n' });
int i = 0;

if (strAllFile.IndexOf("Annualized Production") >= 0) //parse that way 
{
    while (i < arrLines.Length)
    {
        FileToParse RNIC = new FileToParse();

        string test = arrLines[i];
        if (test.IndexOf("\fPROD13") >= 0) //skip to useful info
        {
            i = i + 5;
        }
        else //do everything else
        {
            //create the populated model to be returned


            i++;

        }
```

This is the variable table I am using to store values in for parsing

```
public class Example
{       
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public int BranchID { get; set; }
    public int CompanyID = 1;
    public int WritingNumberID { get; set; }
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string WritingNumber { get; set; }
    public string BranchName { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public decimal NetHouseholdSales { get; set; }
    public decimal RefundPercentage { get; set; }
    public decimal GrossInitialPremium { get; set; }
    public decimal NetPremium { get; set; }
    public decimal BaseNetPremium { get; set; }
    public decimal RefundAmount { get; set; }
    public int Applications { get; set; }
    public int BankDraftApps { get; set; }
    public int ApplicationsSplit { get; set; }
    public int BankDraftAppsSplit { get; set; }
    public int QtyOfRefunds { get; set; }
    public int QtyOfBankDraftRefunds { get; set; }
    public int QtyOfRefundsSplit { get; set; }
    public int QtyOfBankDraftRefundsSplit { get; set; }

}
```

Another issue at hand is that not every line in the file contains the same data types, there are 3 lines at a time that contain useful data, the first line containing one set, and the next two lines containing the same second set except for a different beginning variable.

Comment: It is going to depend on how the data in each line of text is laid out. There are two main methods of laying out tabular data in a text line, character delimited and fixed length field. Character delimited is where the fields are delimited by a particular character e.g. comma, pipe or whatever character is decided upon. Fixed length is where each field is allocated a set number of characters in the line and if they are not all used a pad character fills out the rest of the field.

Comment: you should make a `var parseList = new List<Example>();` then inside of the while loop you will want to populate the List<T> and store it's records into a separate List<T>

Comment: @MethodMan I can make the list easily enough, however this is my first experience with parsing of any kind. How exactly do I go about populating the list?

Comment: is it your first time using google..? do a google search on how to populate the following `List<T> of Class` and`List<T>` of object

Comment: Why not write `regular expressions` w.r.t. to each field.The use `Regex.Match()` to get the fields value then convert them to desired type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"The problem I'm facing is that ... I am unaware how to parse the individual fields of data from each line".

Well, it depends. You didn't tell us what format the data is in, so we don't know how to do it either. Some helpful string methods are: string.Split(), string.Substring(), string.StartsWith(), string.EndsWith(). Or you can get into RegEx.

To convert strings to numbers you can use Parse() methods or call Convert directly:

For example on Substring and Parse: Maybe UserId is *always* 5 characters long and *always* starts at character position 21 of the string: `string UserIdString = test.Substring(21,5);`, then to make it an int: `int UserId = Int32.Parse(UserIdString);`

Split and Convert: Maybe every line is comma-separated and UserId is *always* the 3rd element: `int UserId = Convert.ToInt32(test.Split(',')[2]);`

Comment: The data is in multiple formats, I am pulling literal strings, integers, and decimal values. The first line will look like "Doe, John          RNNY   Refund  %  5.5" followed by two lines of "A+H      321    5     312      62    578,300.62" so on and so forth. Not every line always has the same number of fields, and the fields themselves are different. So line 1 will be storing data to 3 or 4 fields of varying data types, and line 2 will store 10 of varying data types, and line 3 will be the same as line 2 except for the first variable of the line.

Comment: It's up to you to find structure, or ask whoever is making those strings what the structure is. You do not have enough information to "parse" these strings. Someone needs to tell you, "Fields are separated by spaces. If there are 5 fields, then that's a type that always has LastName, FirstName as the first element. But if there's 6 fields then that's a datatype which always has BranchName as the first element and ProductName as the second". Etc.. We can help you turn those words into code, but we cannot tell you how a random string maps to a random datatype.

Comment: I don't think my last comment explained well enough what I wanted it to, but with a little help from a friend and your test.Substring suggestion I think I have it mostly figured out, thank you!